# python smc-api append host to group

Tags: python

I can create hosts and groups. I can ever update hosts with

```
host = Host('TanukiTestHost')
host.update(
     address='3.3.3.3',
     secondary=['12.12.12.12'],
     comment='Tanuki can Edit and Update Seemlessly')
```

Yet when I try to update hosts I get errors.

```
list = Group.create('TanukiTestGroup', [  Host('TanukiTestHost') ])
Group.update('TanukiTestGroup', [  Host('TanukiTestHost2') ])
```

How do I add hosts to a group. I have to make a blank group then update it. I'm not new to python, but I'm not all that good any help would be great.

https://smc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/elements.html
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/smc-python/latest/smc-python.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I was a fool.

```
toupdate=Host('TanukiTestHost2').href
test = Group('TanukiTestGroup')
print(toupdate)
print(test.obtain_members())
test.update_members(
    members=([toupdate]),
    append_lists=True,
    remove_members=False
    )
print(test.obtain_members())
```

Lets say you also want to remove a host from a group

```
toupdate=Host('TanukiTestHost2').href
test = Group('TanukiTestGroup')
print(toupdate)
print(test.obtain_members())
test.update_members(
    members=([toupdate]),
    remove_members=True
    )
print(test.obtain_members())
```

I should have looked at the documentation a little more closely.